# Why Storyboard isn't compatible with <= iOS4?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios-simulator

I want to know why my app devlop within storybord is not compatible to <=iOS4.

Comment: <= iOS4 should be more correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storyboard was introduced with iOs 5

Answer (score 2):

Because the libraries needed to use StoryBoard framework are not present in iOS 4 or previous releases.

Comment: is it possible to add some librairies in IOS4 to make it compatible with storyboard?

Comment: No, you cant add framework like the once used by storyboards to iOS < 5